# AWS instance hanging up when running huge computations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a ML algorithm on image recognition dataset in AWS EC2 instance. The algorithm takes long time(>6) hours to run and I am not sure how to keep the instance up all this time.

I tried couple of times kicking off the code and see that connection is lost after an hour or so. How can I prevent this from happening.

To give more detail, I am running a Convolution neural network from jupyter notebook. I access this jupyter notebook from my local machine using port forwarding from AWS
https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh#comment_28219

Thanks in advance

Comment: What size EC2 instance are you running?  Are there any errors being logged to the log file that explain why the instance crashes/hangs up.  If you're running on a micro tier the computation may just be too large for the hardware.  (Just suggestions as you haven't really provided much in terms of your configuration)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I am on premium 16gb EC2 with 16 GB RAM. This is not any corporate instance but one I spun up on my personal account

Comment: I see it's being called as m4.xlarge in my I stance type

Answer (score 2):

Try running your command (or code) in a screen. Refer https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/. This ensures that your command keeps running in the background even if the ssh connection drops. ssh again and open the screen.

Important commands:

```
screen -S <name> : creates the screen 
screen -ls : list all screens
screen -r <name> : restore the screen
```

Comment: I can try that but one common trend I noticed is that it happens when my cpu utilization shoots up above 90%. When I run my model with complete dataset, I see that cpu util > 90% consistently. Could that be a reason. I ask because when I run same code on my local, same thing happens but atleast system does not shut down